# MATLAB I would like to minimize the difference fitting

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a curve that looks like an exponentiel function, I would like to fit this curve with this equation :

[image]

The goal is to find the value of `A`, `T` and `d` which will minimize `V` with my initial curve.

I did a function that is able to do it but it takes 10 seconds to run. 
3 loops that test all the values that I want to and at the end of the 3 loops I calculate the RMSD (root mean square deviation) between my 2 curves and I put the result in a vector `min_RMSN`, at the end I check the minimum value of `min_RMSD` and it's done...

But this is not the best way for sure.

Thank you for your help, ideas :)

Comment: Have you tried Matlab's Curve Fitting Toolbox?

Comment: Post your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab has a built in [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) function that does pretty much exactly what you want. You define a function handle that takes the RMSE of your data vs. the function fit, pass in your initial guess for `A`, `T` and `d`, and get a result:

```
x0 = [A0, T0, d0]
fn = @(x) sum((x(1) * (1 - exp(-x[2] / (t - x[3]))) - y).^2)
V = fminsearch(@fn, x0)
```

Here `t` is the x-data for the curve you have, `y` are the corresponding y-values and, `A0`, `T0`, `d0` are the initial guesses for your parameters. `fn` computes the suquare of the RMSE between your ideal curve and `y`. No need to take the square root since you minimizing the square will also minimize the RMSE itself, and computing square roots takes time.

Comment: Click on the up arrow above the check mark you used to select. Same as for other questions and answers you like.

Comment: perfect. Done. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, @MadPhysicist. my function was working correctly and suddenly I have this error : Exiting: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded
         - increase MaxFunEvals option.
         Current function value: NaN. I tried to change MaxFunEvals to 1000000 but it still does not work...

Comment: @YLM. The most likely cause is that you have a bad initial guess because some of the parameters have changed. The NaN could happen if, for example, it went off to an incorrect local minimum that made `d` greater than `t`. I would recommend coming up with some procedure to get a reasonable first order approximation to pass in as the initial guess.

Comment: Great! thanks for answering so quickly. It was exactly that. I had some NaN value in my vector... Thanks again !